# Decoding base64 with java.util.Base64.Decoder

Tags: xslt, saxon

I´m trying to decode an input String to base64 inside my XSLT.

I have defined 2 namespaces:

```
xmlns:base64Decoder="java:java.util.Base64.Decoder"
xmlns:base64="java:java.util.Base64"
```

and this is my simple try:

```
        <xsl:variable name="base64Value" select="'aGVsbG8='"/>
        <xsl:variable name="deco" select="base64:getDecoder()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="base64Decoder:decode($deco, $base64Value)"/>
```

The execution doesn´t compile and shows me the message:

*Cannot find a matching 2-argument function named {java:java.util.Base64.Decoder}decode()*

I know there´re another approaches but I´m specially interested to know why this one isn´t working.

Thanks in advance.

Adding Oxygen diagnosis info for resolving method invocations (see the trace: "The class java.util.Base64.Decoder could not be loaded: java.util.Base64.Decoder" almost at the end):

```
Looking for function {java:java.util.Base64}getDecoder
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.SystemFunctionLibrary
Trying net.sf.saxon.style.StylesheetFunctionLibrary
Trying com.saxonica.functions.extfn.ExtraFunctionLibrary
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.ConstructorFunctionLibrary
Trying net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryFunctionLibrary
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.IntegratedFunctionLibrary
Trying com.saxonica.config.JavaExtensionLibrary
Looking for method getDecoder in namespace java:java.util.Base64
Number of actual arguments = 0
Loading java.util.Base64
Looking in Java class class java.util.Base64
Trying method getMimeDecoder: name does not match
Trying method getDecoder: name matches
Method is static
Method has 0 arguments; expecting 0
Found a candidate method:
    public static java.util.Base64$Decoder java.util.Base64.getDecoder()
Trying method getEncoder: name does not match
Trying method getMimeEncoder: name does not match
Trying method getMimeEncoder: name does not match
Trying method getUrlDecoder: name does not match
Trying method getUrlEncoder: name does not match
Trying method wait: name does not match
Trying method wait: name does not match
Trying method wait: name does not match
Trying method equals: name does not match
Trying method toString: name does not match
Trying method hashCode: name does not match
Trying method getClass: name does not match
Trying method notify: name does not match
Trying method notifyAll: name does not match
Looking for function {java:java.util.Base64.Decoder}decode
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.SystemFunctionLibrary
Trying net.sf.saxon.style.StylesheetFunctionLibrary
Trying com.saxonica.functions.extfn.ExtraFunctionLibrary
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.ConstructorFunctionLibrary
Trying net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryFunctionLibrary
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.IntegratedFunctionLibrary
Trying com.saxonica.config.JavaExtensionLibrary
Looking for method decode in namespace java:java.util.Base64.Decoder
Number of actual arguments = 2
Loading java.util.Base64.Decoder
The class java.util.Base64.Decoder could not be loaded: java.util.Base64.Decoder
Trying net.sf.saxon.style.StylesheetFunctionLibrary
Function {java:java.util.Base64.Decoder}decode not found!
Loading java.util.Base64.Decoder
The class java.util.Base64.Decoder could not be loaded: java.util.Base64.Decoder
```

Comment: So which version of which XSLT processor exactly do you use? Calling into Java is not standardized and how you do not depends on the particular XSLT processor.

Comment: Thanks for noticing: I´m using Saxon PE 9.4 in XSLT 2.0 and running under Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is found if you use the Java internal class name:

```
xmlns:base64Decoder="java:java.util.Base64$Decoder"
```

Unfortunately you then get another problem:

```
Static error in xsl:value-of/@select on line 16 column 71 of test.xsl:
  XPST0017: There is more than one method matching the function call base64Decoder:decode,
  and there is insufficient type information to determine which one should be used
```

You can get around this by writing the call as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="base64Decoder:decode($deco, $base64Value treat as xs:string)"/>
```

The code then runs successfully and prints the output

```
104 101 108 108 111
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr. Kay. Now, if I wanted to print that byte array to readable text, I´d use the equivalent in XSLT of: String result = new String(<previous result>), but the  XSLT compiler says "There is more than one method matching the function call javaString:new, and there is insufficient type information to determine which one should be used". Is there any way of specifying in SAXON XSLT the type "byte[]" so the "new String()" matched? Thanks again. Regards.

Comment: Fixed! it seems that using the constructor: String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName) there´s no ambiguity: <xsl:value-of select="javaString:new($byteResult, 'UTF-8')"/>. Anyway, it would be interesting to know how to distinguish in XSLT a byte[] object to resolve which method should be used. Thanks!

Comment: It's a somewhat academic question since you can do all of this with functions defined in the expath Binary module rather than developing it yourself...

Comment: More specifically, see http://expath.org/spec/binary#decode-string which is implemented in recent Saxon releases though I'm not sure about 9.4. But there's also the earlier https://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/base64Binary-to-string

Comment: Thank you very much again, Mr Kay: your help is very appreciated. Anyway, my underlying concern was how to resolve this kind of Java type conflicts in Saxon XSL, but surely the best option is to avoid them as much as we can. Best regards.

Comment: As a general approach, my preference is to write a static Java method that's explicitly designed for calling from XSLT/XPath, rather than trying to call what's already there.